# Setting up phpmyadmin to be accessible to one subdomain only

Tags: php, nginx, dns

I set up phpmyadmin via nginx. Problems are that the php page can be accessed to whatever subdomains / IP.
To explain it further, data.domain.com should only be used to access the php page, not node.domain.com / etc.domain.com and most importantly -IP-
Is this an internal issue or is this an issue to the DNS record?
Thanks for all help.

This is my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/phpmyadmin.conf` config:

```
    
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name data.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name data.domain.com;

    root /var/www/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php;

    # allow larger file uploads and longer script runtimes
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    client_body_timeout 120s;

    sendfile off;

    # SSL Configuration
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/data.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/data.domain.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers 'CIPHERS-here>
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # See https://hstspreload.org/ before uncommenting the line below.
    # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; preload;";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self'";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header Referrer-Policy same-origin;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "upload_max_filesize = 100M \n post_max_size=100M";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
```

I have tried to search up this problem on google but I have only found answers for apache users only.

Comment: I didn't understand. However, domain names can be spoofed, I mean using `hosts` file and IP of server, you can fool the server to believe you are accessing it as `any.domain.com`

Comment: It looks like data.domain.com is the default server. Degrade data.domain.com, it must no longer be the default server. Cf. https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html